# Sending and receiving a TMemoryStream using IdTCPClient and IdTCPServer

Tags: delphi, tcp, indy

I found Remy Lebeau's chat demo of IdTCP components in XE2 and I wanted to play with it a little bit. (It can be found [here](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=65247&tstart=105)) I would like to send a picture using these components and the best approach seems to be using TMemoryStream. If I send strings, the connection works fine, the strings are transmitted successfully, however when I change it to Stream instead, it doesn't work. Here is the code:

**Server**

```
procedure TMainForm.IdTCPServerExecute(AContext: TIdContext);
var rcvdMsg: string;
  ms:TMemoryStream;
begin
// This commented code is working, it receives and sends strings.
//  rcvdMsg:=AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLn;
//  LogMessage('<ServerExec> '+rcvdMsg);
//
//  TResponseSync.SendResponse(AContext, rcvdMsg);
  try
    ms:=TMemoryStream.Create;
    AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadStream(ms);

    ms.SaveToFile('c:\networked.bmp');
  except
    LogMessage('Failed to receive',clred);
  end;
end;
```

**Client**

```
procedure TfrmMain.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var ms: TMemoryStream;
    bmp: TBitmap;
    pic: TPicture;
    s: string;
begin
  // Again, this code is working for sending strings.
  // s:=edMsg.Text;
  // Client.IOHandler.WriteLn(s);
  ms:=TMemoryStream.Create;

  pic:=TPicture.Create;
  pic.LoadFromFile('c:\Back.png');

  bmp:=TBitmap.Create;
  bmp.Width:=pic.Width;
  bmp.Height:=pic.Height;
  bmp.Canvas.Draw(0,0,pic.Graphic);

  bmp.SaveToStream(ms);
  ms.Position:=0;
  Client.IOHandler.Write(ms);
  ms.Free;
end;
```

When I try to send the stream from the client, nothing observable happens (breakpoint in the OnExecute doesn't fire). However, when closing the programs(after sending the MemoryStream), two things happen:

- If the Client is closed first, only then does the `except` part get processed (the log displays the 'Failed to receive' error. However, even if I place a breakpoint on the first line of the try-except block, it somehow gets skipped and only the error is displayed).
- If the Server is closed first, the IDE doesn't change back from *debug*, Client doesn't change its state to *disconnected* (as it normally does when server disconnects) and after the Client is closed as well, an Access Violation error from the Server app appears. I guess this means that there is a thread of the Server still running and maintaining the connection. But no matter how much time i give it, it never completes the task of receiving the MemoryStream.

Note: The server uses `IdSchedulerOfThreadDefault` and `IdAntiFreeze`, if that matters.

As I can't find any reliable source of help for the revamped Indy 10 (it all appears to apply for the older Indy 10, or even Indy 9), I hope you can tell me what is wrong. Thanks

---

**- ANSWER -**

**SERVER**

```
procedure TMainForm.IdTCPServerExecute(AContext: TIdContext);
var size: integer;
    ms:TMemoryStream;
begin
  try
    ms:=TMemoryStream.Create;
    size:=AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLongInt;
    AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadStream(ms, size);

    ms.SaveToFile('c:\networked.bmp');
  except
    LogMessage('Failed to receive',clred);
  end;
end;
```

**CLIENT**

```
procedure TfrmMain.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var ms: TMemoryStream;
    bmp: TBitmap;
    pic: TPicture;
begin
  ms:=TMemoryStream.Create;

  pic:=TPicture.Create;
  pic.LoadFromFile('c:\Back.png');

  bmp:=TBitmap.Create;
  bmp.Width:=pic.Width;
  bmp.Height:=pic.Height;
  bmp.Canvas.Draw(0,0,pic.Graphic);

  bmp.SaveToStream(ms);
  ms.Position:=0;
  Client.IOHandler.Write(ms, 0, True);
  ms.Free;
end;
```

Comment: send the size of the stream first so the server knows exactly how many bytes it needs to read.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use the proper parameters:

```
.IOHandler.Write(ms, 0, true); //true ... indicates WriteByteCount

.IOHandler.ReadStream(ms, -1); //-1 ... use ByteCount
```

Comment: even better than my solution :)

Comment: @whosrdaddy: its actually the same, only that this functunality is already included.

Comment: Awesome, it now works even without the need to disconnect and reconnect the client. I will update my question for the sake of integrity. 

Because the answers of both of you guys were practically the same, I don't know which one to give the *accepted answer*.. I will give it to the shorter version, but thanks nevertheless, *whosrdaddy*

Comment: FYI, it is the combination of the `AByteCount` and `AReadUntilDisconnect` parameters working together that determines whether `ReadStream()` will expects a preceeding byte count or not. It is not the `AByteCount` parameter by itself. Only when `AByteCount=-1` *and* `AReadUntilDisconnect=False` will `ReadStream()` expect a preceeding byte count. And these are the default values for both parameters.

Answer (score 3):

Send the size of the stream upfront so that the server knows how many bytes it must read.

Server:

```
procedure TMainForm.IdTCPServerExecute(AContext: TIdContext);
var rcvdMsg: string;
  ms:TMemoryStream;
  size : integer;
begin
// This commented code is working, it receives and sends strings.
//  rcvdMsg:=AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLn;
//  LogMessage('<ServerExec> '+rcvdMsg);
//
//  TResponseSync.SendResponse(AContext, rcvdMsg);
  try
    ms:=TMemoryStream.Create;
    try 
     size := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLongint; 
     AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadStream(ms, size, false);
     ms.SaveToFile('c:\networked.bmp');
    finally
     ms.Free;
    end;        
  except
    LogMessage('Failed to receive',clred);
  end;
end;
```

Client (Fixed resource handling)

```
procedure TfrmMain.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var ms: TMemoryStream;
    bmp: TBitmap;
    pic: TPicture;
    s: string;
begin
  // Again, this code is working for sending strings.
  // s:=edMsg.Text;
  // Client.IOHandler.WriteLn(s);
  ms:=TMemoryStream.Create;
  pic:=TPicture.Create;
  bmp:=TBitmap.Create;
  try
   pic.LoadFromFile('c:\Back.png');   
   bmp.Width:=pic.Width;
   bmp.Height:=pic.Height;
   bmp.Canvas.Draw(0,0,pic.Graphic);
   bmp.SaveToStream(ms);
   ms.Position:=0;
   Client.IOHandler.Write(ms.Size);
   Client.IOHandler.Write(ms);
  finally
   ms.Free;
   bmp.Free;
   pic.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, in a way. Both apps still get 'stuck' and only after quitting the client does server write "Failed to receive" error. But despite that error, the picture *is* saved correctly on the hard drive. So it appears that the transmission completed fine, but didn't *end*, for some reason

Comment: The server tries to receive the next picture in the Execute loop. Simply disconnect the client after sending the picture should fix the problem as the server notices the closed socket and stops.

Comment: Is this really the correct way? I mean, I might be sending more pictures, only on client-demand, so connecting and disconnecting all the time seems a bit weird to me. Anyway, OnExecute should only be fired when data comes to the server, it's not a loop, right?

Comment: @MartinMelka do not swallow exceptions in the Execute handler as Indy uses exceptions to detect the disconnect. This explains why the server gests stuck. And btw sending pictures in a loop without disconnecting works fine with the code above.

Comment: Yes, I noticed a wrong line of code and it now works. Does that mean that when working with Indy, I should never use try-except blocks?

Comment: @Martin, did you ever resolve the question `Does that mean that when working with Indy, I should never use try-except blocks?` ?  My understanding of Indy is that there are situations where trapping in a `try..except` block is the *only* way of determining whether something worked (e.g. `TIdTCPClient.Connect`).