# Access violation to server in Delphi

Tags: delphi, tcp, memorystream

Was trying to write simple client and server recieveing/sending data through `TMemoryStream`. When I push button in client `btnTestClick` it apperas an error
`Access violation at address 005D5581 in module 'Client.exe'. Write of adress 00000000`. What I do wrong?

Btw client server connection works okay I thin cuz `IdTCPClient1Connected` function is writing `'Client Connected!'`.

Client code

```
procedure TForm1.btnTestClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  msRecInfo: TMemoryStream;
  arrOf: array of Integer; i:integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to 10 do
    arrOf[i]:=random(100);

  msRecInfo:= TMemoryStream.Create;

  try
    msRecInfo.Write(arrOf, SizeOf(arrOf));
    idTCPClient1.IOHandler.Write(msRecInfo);
  finally
     msRecInfo.Free;
  end;

end;

end
```

Server code

```
procedure TForm1.IdTCPServer1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
   msRecInfo: TMemoryStream;
  arrOf: array of Integer; i:integer;
begin
  msRecInfo:= TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadStream(msRecInfo, -1, False);

    msRecInfo.Position := 0;
    msRecInfo.Read(arrof, SizeOf(arrof));
  finally
    memo1.Lines.Add(IntToStr(arrOf[1]));
    msRecInfo.Free;
  end;
  //AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadStream(msRecInfo, SizeOf(arrOf));
  //msRecInfo.Read(arrOf, sizeOf(arrOf));
end;
```

Comment: At first look you're not setting the length of your arrOf, also will need to correct SizeOf(arrOf).

Comment: Why did you include so much irrelevant code? You already knew the problem had nothing to do with the server, didn't you? You knew the problem was limited to just the btnTestClick method, so that's all you should have included here.

Comment: @RobKennedy sorry, i just used ctrl+a cuz it faster

Comment: @RobKennedy Well, yep I fixed it. And now `memo1.Lines.Add(IntToStr(arrOf[1]));` not working. Why could it be? I mean i push button, but in server memo nothing appears

Comment: Faster for whom? For you, or for the people you're asking to solve your problems?

Comment: @RobKennedy sorry again, i'll edit my question

Comment: There's lots more wrong with your code. Beyond not allocating the array. For a start, `msRecInfo.Write(arrOf, SizeOf(arrOf));` writes a pointer. You don't want to do that. And the reading code is all wrong too. Anyway, Rob answered the question that you asked. You can't expect him to debug all the bugs in your code.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan well, sir, i just look at some examples whch I was able to find. Like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12159868/sending-and-receiving-a-tmemorystream-using-idtcpclient-and-idtcpserver) or [there](http://delphi.about.com/od/internetintranet/l/aa012004c.htm) but still don't understand my problem. Damn, I just stucked with all this stuff.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You start writing into a dynamic array before you've allocated any elements for it. Dynamic arrays do not automatically grow like you might be used to from some other languages. You need to set their lengths first.

If you haven't set the length of a dynamic array, then it will just be a null pointer, which explains why you get an access violation at address 0.

Change your btnTestClick method like so:

```
var
  msRecInfo: TMemoryStream;
  arrOf: array of Integer;
  i: integer;
begin
  SetLength(arrOf, 11);
  for i := 0 to 10 do
    arrOf[i] := Random(100);
```

Comment: I should add, when disposing of this array, you should also do `SetLength(MyArray, 0);` to free this memory. I've seen strange behavior if you don't.